# XOR JOIN in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have the following tables

**Table A**

```
ID "Other Columns"  
1  
2  
3
```

**Table B**

```
ID "Other Columns"  
3  
4  
5
```

What is the efficient way to return the below result?
**Result**

```
ID "Other Columns"  
1  
2  
4  
5
```

Answer (score 8):

A full outer join should work, and only go through each table once. They can be tricky, so test carefully!

```
SELECT
   isnull(A.ID, B.ID)  ID
  ,"Other columns"  --  Handle nulls properly!
 from TableA  A
  full outer joing TableB  B
   on B.ID = A.ID
 where not (A.ID is not null
            and B.ID is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You want to use left and right join and union them

Select TableA.ID as 'ID','Other Colums'
FROM TableA Left join TableB
ON TableA.ID=TableB.ID
WHERE TableB.ID IS NULL
UNION
Select TableB.ID as 'ID','Other Colums'
FROM TableA Right join TableB
ON TableA.ID=TableB.ID
WHERE TableA.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(a.id, b.id),
    OtherColumns
FROM #tablea a
FULL JOIN #tableb b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id IS NULL
OR b.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `UNION ALL` using a `LEFT JOIN` to determine if the `ID` is not in the other table.  Keep in mind that the column count and datatypes between the two tables must match up:

```
Select      A.Id, A.OtherColumns
From        TableA  A
Left Join   TableB  B   On  A.Id = B.Id
Where       B.Id Is Null
Union All
Select      B.Id, B.OtherColumns
From        TableB  B
Left Join   TableA  A   On  A.Id = B.Id
Where       A.Id Is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you need with the "Other columns", but you could use EXCEPT:

```
Select ID from TableA
EXCEPT
Select ID from TableB
```

If you need Other columns from TableA you could use:

```
Select ID, OtherColumn1, OtherColumn2 from TableA
where ID not in (select ID from TableB)
```

(as long as ID cannot be null in TableB)

Answer (score 0):

I broke down each part to be clearer!

```
select *  
into #temp
from
TabA Full outer join TabB
on TabA.ColNameA = TabB.ColNameB

select * 
into #temp2
from #temp
where (ColNameA is Null Or ColNameB is null)

select ColNameA from #temp2
where  ColNameA Is not null
union 
select ColNameB from #temp2
where ColNameB Is not null
```