# BigQuery: Symmetric difference (xor) between two sets

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

BigQuery has UNION, INTERSECT, and EXCEPT [1], but not XOR.

`SELECT * FROM [0, 1,2,3] XOR SELECT * FROM [2,3,4]`

would return
0
1
4

As 0 and 1 are present in the first select but not second, and 4 is present in the second select, but not first.

I'd like to use it to find discrepancies between two tables, eg find customers that are present in one table, but not other and vice versa.

Any hints how to best do it?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#set_operators

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by 'discrepancies', but isn't LEFT AND RIGHT JOINS supose to do that. Just scrolled through docs on link that you provided and there are both operations.

Answer (score 2):

Few 'workarounds'

Option 1

```
with table1 as (
  select * from unnest([0, 1,2,3]) num
), table2 as (
  select * from unnest([2,3,4]) num
  )
select * from table1 where not num in (select num from table2)
union all 
select * from table2 where not num in (select num from table1)
```

Option 2

```
with table1 as (
  select * from unnest([0,1,2,3]) num
), table2 as (
  select * from unnest([2,3,4]) num
)
select num from (
  select distinct num from table1 union all 
  select distinct num from table2 
)
group by num
having count(*) = 1
```

in both cases  - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery does not need a XOR operator as it can be obtained from existing operators:

a first way to do so as @Genato points it out is to use `JOIN` like in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777908/xor-join-in-sql)

Another way is to use set operators: A XOR B can be translated as (A AND NOT B) OR (B AND NOT A), so with your example you could write

```
(
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<int64>[0, 1, 2, 3]) AS number
EXCEPT DISTINCT SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<int64>[2, 3, 4]) AS number)

UNION ALL

(
    SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<int64>[2,3,4]) AS number
EXCEPT DISTINCT SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY<int64>[0, 1, 2, 3]) AS number);
```

which results in:

[image]